# I dont know why my app is returning undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, undefined, public-html

When I add this code to my app.js in the express server

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html')), function(err) {             
   if (err) {                 
       res.status(500).send(err) 
       }        
    };
 })
```

The console print the following error when I make a request, except fot the signin page which works good.

```
    Type error: cannot read
    react-dom.production.min.js:216 
    
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Resultados.js:2368:16
```

Without adding that code lines, the app works okey, except when I refresh the page, because in the browser appear the message cannot get.

Why without the code the app is not returning undefined?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.sendFile` only sends `index.html` file and other files in your public folder are inaccessible. Serve your public folder like this

```
const path = require('path')
const publicFolder = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
app.use('/*', express.static(publicFolder))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Is there any relevance that my front end was deployed in react?, because still is not working.

Comment: Finally works, thank you.

Comment: No problem. This problem would have occurred even if weren't using React so It's not related to React